# Basic Consistently sized outline with depth

Tags: grease-pencil, freestyle, lineart

I am struggling to create a very simple outline because of its criteria.
I would like the outline to not draw atop the object and affect the object's size, and the width to scale as if it were an object in the scene.

The obvious first choice is **freestyle**:

[image: Object Freestyle]

However, this has gaps in the strokes, contours between the finers in an unappealing way, and carves into the object's size. Here's the object's original size as reference:

[image: Object Alone]

My next solution is an **inverted hull** that is composited behind the object. This works the best so far. It is consistently size, looks clean, and doesn't bother contouring the fingers. The finger contour is the reason I render it behind in compositing. Because of this, however, when intersecting with objects it will render behind unless I manually layer every object, which gets complicated when animating.

[image: Composited Inverted Hull]

My final attempt was a **stroke** with the **line art** modifier. This does stay a consistent size, and renders behind or in front of objects automatically, but can't seem to be forced to draw behind the object. There is a setting to offset it's position relative to the camera, but there is a hard cap to -0.1m for some reason.

[image: Offset]

[image: Line art stroke modifier]